# MongoDB add and subtract not work simultaneously on aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have the schema like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c35f04c4e92b8337885d9a6"),
    "activity" : {
        "a": 10,
        "b": 20,
        "c": 30,
        "d": 40
    }
}
```

Now I would like to perform addition and subtraction with some multiplication, for that I wrote the query but this query is working fine on only addition, not with subtraction. My query is this:

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: ObjectId("5c35f04c4e92b8337885d9a6") } },
  { $unwind: "$_id" },
  {
    $project: {
      "activity.score": {
        $add: [
          {
            $multiply: [
              "$activity.a",
              0.5
            ]
          },
          {
            $multiply: [
              "$activity.b",
              0.5
            ]
          }
        ],
        $subtract: [
          {
            $multiply: [
              "$activity.c",
              0.2
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

by this getting the error i.e

```
'Invalid $project :: caused by :: an expression specification must contain exactly one field, the name of the expression.
```

If I removed the subtract part then it working fine.

Anyone can suggest me where I done the mistake. Any help or suggestion is really appreciated

Comment: `activity.score` should only take one field. And also `$subtract` takes two expression you have only given single. What output do you expect?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet 10*0.5 -  20*0.2 = 1

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet on addition block n number will be there similarly for subtraction case

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    $project: {
      "activity.score": {
        $subtract: [{$add: [
          {
            $multiply: [
              "$activity.a",
              0.5
            ]
          },
          {
            $multiply: [
              "$activity.b",
              0.5
            ]
          }
        ]},
        {
            $multiply: [
              "$activity.c",
              0.2
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).